# Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs Removed

Tags: xdb

We are working through upgrading from `9.1` to `10.2`, changing various API calls where there are now removed methods, etc.

One method's update we are having trouble locating is `Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs` - we are using this method to track contacts as part of a service. Can anyone assist with what might be the replacement for this method in 10.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/identifying-contacts.html) shows the new API for this.

Basically:

1. Inject `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.IContactIdentificationManager` to your class
2. 

Code:

```
var result = identificationManager.IdentifyAs(new Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Identification.KnownContactIdentifier("twitter", "myidentifier"));

if(!result.Success)
{
    //check result.ErrorCode and result.ErrorMessage for more details
}
```