# 'Session' does not contain a definition for 'IdentifyAs' and no accessible extension method 'IdentifyAs' accepting a first argument of type 'Session'Z

Tags: xdb, upgrade

We are upgrading our Project from 9.3 to 10.3.1
While doing that we were facing error
and no accessible extension method 'IdentifyAs' accepting a first argument of type 'Session' could be found

```
"'Session' does not contain a definition for 'IdentifyAs' and no accessible extension method 'IdentifyAs' accepting a first argument of type 'Session' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Foundation.Xdb"
```

Have seen the article but it is not much helpful.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/identifying-contacts.html

Comment: What is your original code from 9.3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/tracker-current-session-identifyas-removed